# What kind of hook_entity can be trigerred by a migration on this entity?

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I have a custom content entity on which I can run a dedicated migration from csv with a form.
The form is used to

1. upload the csv file
2. launch the migration

The submit part of the form:

```
  $fileId = $form_state->getValue('file_to_import')[0];
  $file = file_load($fileId);
  $uri = $file->uri->value;
  $filename = $file->filename->value;
  $filenamenew = 'migration_UpdateMembers.csv';
  $urinew = 'private://migration_UpdateMembers.csv';
  $file->setFilename($filenamenew);
  $file->setFileUri($urinew);
  $file->save();
  rename($uri, $urinew);

  $migration_id = 'migration_updatemembers';
  $migration = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.migration')->createInstance($migration_id);
  $executable = new MigrateExecutable($migration, new MigrateMessage());
  $executable->import();
```

The corresponding Migration .yaml is:

```
id: migration_updatemembers
migration_tags: null
migration_group: null
label: 'Update Member from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: sites/default/files/_private/migration_UpdateMembers.csv
  delimiter: ';'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - id
process:
  id: id
  status: status
  enddate: enddate
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:member'
migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
  optional: {}
```

I assumed that, as the migration updates the entity content, hook__entity_update would be fired. And it is not! Not as I expected...
Here is my hook__entity_update:

```
function association_entity_update(EntityInterface $entity)
{
ksm($entity);
  $mode = 'update';
  switch ($entity->getEntityType()->id()) {
    case "member":
      break;
    case "person":
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

As far as I understand the result of `ksm` see below), it seems that it is the `$file->save();` that triggers the hook. And it fires only once. Not for any 'member' update...
[image]

Comment: Could you post your migration YAML? And yes typical migration will fire Entity API hooks and events

Comment: I updated my question with the migration.yaml

Comment: Have you verified that your hook works correctly by manually changing an entity in the edit form?

Comment: As @Hudri points out, check first that your hook is called when editing the entity using the UI. Also core's migrate destination plugin `entity` should support any entity out-of-box due a deriver so a custom entity shouldn't be a problem also your YAML looks fine.

Comment: It definitely works. Post your hook code.

Comment: Is the name of the module 'association'?

Comment: Yes, hook works as expected when manually updating a 'member'.
Yes, module name is 'association'
I updated my question to give more details.

Comment: Hmm I think maybe is because the members are already mapped so migrate doesn't "migrate" them if the source does not change. You need to force the migration update check this comment https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2764287#comment-12763831

Comment: I'm a bit confused: finally, it works as expected. It seems it was more an issue with the handling of uploaded file that was preventing to run the migration multiple times in a row. I added a `$file->delete()` at the end of `submitForm`...